# Document Clustering in Java using Weka

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, classification, weka, k-means

I'm trying to cluster a group of news articles in Java that are about a particular topic.  I crawled news sites about a particular topic using Crawler4J, rolled my own TF/IDF implementation comparing against a corpus (there were reasons that I didn't use the built in Weka or other implementations of TF/IDF, but they're probably out of scope for this question) and applied some other domain specific logic which leaves me with a bag of words + weights for each document (which I'm storing in a Map where the value is between 0 and 1).  I want to cluster the articles that are about a similar topic by looking at word weights, so I started playing with Weka's EM and SimpleKMeans clusterers.  The problem is that I'm getting pretty unimpressive results, and I'm trying to figure out whether I can do anything to better tune the clustering.

For example in a toy data set of ~300 articles if I trim the words to the top 20 in each document and then use the full set of words as features I end up with ~2k unique features.  I'm using each article as a training instance, and trying some different parameters to tune the SimpleKMeans clusterer (for example ~20-30 clusters, 100 max iterations).  When I look at the data at a glance I see that the keywords for a lot of the articles seem very closely related, so I would expect high quality results and a bunch of clusters that contain ~5-10 articles.  Unfortunately the results are usually one cluster with > half of the articles, a bunch of clusters with 1 article each, and a few stragglers with 2-5 articles or so.

Are these results expected, or is there a way to get higher quality results?  Note that I've also looked into LingPipe and other frameworks that provide clustering functionality, and played with rolling my own EM implementation (with modest but not great success).  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you normalize the tf-idf vectors before feeding them to k-means? That usually helps (use L2, aka Euclidean, normalization). Also language model weighting might work better than tf-idf.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into normalization since I'm not understanding what it does at a glance.  Looks like Weka provides a Normalize vector that may be useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several tricks to make *k*-means work for text:

1. Get rid of the terms that occur in only a few documents (that have low df). These artificially blow up the distances in vector space.
2. Normalize vectors. That helps a bit, since it gets rid of length differences between documents. It also makes document vectors have similar variances, as pointed out by @Anony-Mousse.
3. Perform dimensionality reduction using [LSA](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/18lsi.pdf), aka truncated [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), before doing the actual clustering. That helps a lot. (Be sure to normalize the LSA results as well.)

Short explanation of why normalization works: suppose you have three documents {d₁, d₂, d₃}, and the tiny vocabulary {cat, dog, tax}. The term-document matrix (raw counts or tf-idf, doesn't matter) looks like

```
   | cat | dog | tax
d₁ | 100 | 100 |   0
d₂ |  10 |  10 |   0
d₃ |   0 |   0 | 100
```

Now we're going to do 2-means. We can reasonably expect to find a pets cluster {d₁, d₂} and a finance singleton cluster {d₃}. However, the distances between the pairs are

```
D(d₁, d₂) = 127.28
D(d₁, d₃) = 173.21
D(d₂, d₃) = 101.00
```

so a density-based method like *k*-means will tend to group d₂ with d₃. By normalizing the vectors, you effectively map both d₁ and d₂ to the same vector [0.71, 0.71, 0] so D(d₁, d₂) = 0 and they will always be in the same cluster.

(*k*-means applied to normalized vectors is sometimes called "spherical" *k*-means because unit vectors lie on a hypersphere centered at the origin.)

Comment: Really appreciate the info.  I'm already normalizing, the tfidf values for my keywords are floats between 0 and 1.  My feature selection is pretty dumb though, as I mentioned in my explanation my dumb initial implementation is to consider any term that is in the top 30 for any article a feature and use it in clustering.  I will experiment with LSA tonight, examples are pretty sparse so any pointers to using LSA in Java code would be super helpful.  Per @Anony-Mousse's question, are you confident that K-Means will be a good fit with good feature selection or should I try other clusterers?

Comment: I played with #1/3 (trim low frequency, use LSA to reduce dimentionality) and the results are slightly better. 44% of the articles still fall into one cluster, but there are 7 clusters with 5+ articles which seems to fit the data better. How do I map the post LSA instances to my original ones? Do I depend on index and assume that order is preserved?

Comment: @Tyson: there's no reason why the order should not be preserved (unless you have a really buggy implementation).

Answer (score 2):

If you have bag of words and their weights then you should first calculate some similarity measure between them. As for example Jacquard Similarity, Cosine Similarity....Then with this base you can cluster your articles using K-Means or other clustering algorithms.

If you know that the news articles can only be of fixed types like sports, entertainment, history, politics etc then I suggest you use classification algorithms rather than clustering algorithms this will increase your probability of getting good and impressive result.

And if really want to use clustering algorithm go for some extended algorithms that can produce dynamic clusters(Nearest-Neighbour, Genetic Algorithms, Quality Threshold, Minimum Spanning Tree...).

Answer (score 1):

Both k-means and EM model clusters by their mean vector, and similarity is based on Euclidean resp. Mahalanobis distance.

The problem is that **the mean is probably not sensible for sparse data**. This is best seen by the fact that the means are less sparse than the documents. Furthermore, it may even occur that the means become more similar to each other than to the actual documents.

So IMHO you are just using an inappropriate clustering algorithm for your data. Sometimes it may work okay, but sometimes it will just fail, because the method was designed for dense data of the same variance in each axis.

Comment: Thanks for the response, although I admittedly don't understand all of it (and share larsmans question).  Can you suggest a different clustering algorithm (and/or a way to prepare/filter the data) that I should experiment with?